# Is there a live video feed module?

Tags: 7

Is there a way to let visitors to my site watch a video via a live stream?

For example, I want to let students watch a course in which a professor lectures live?

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 3):

Try [BigBlueButton](http://drupal.org/project/bbb)

BigBlueButton Demo, http://demo.bigbluebutton.org/

Answer (score 3):

A stable module for streaming live videos for drupal 7 is [VideoWhisper Live Streaming](http://drupal.org/project/vls). You could try using it.

Answer (score 2):

Live Stream A Drupal 7 Site Free No Hosting Fees

CREATE LIVE STREAMING WEB PAGE IN DRUPAL USING CKEDITOR

Required Modules:

CKeditor

Admin Menu

GET STARTED

1. Go to your Drupal Website and hover over content and create a basic page
2. Click the Green Film Icon at the top in the toolbar section of your editor and keep the window open

Note: If you do not have the green film  icon then you will need to add it to your CKeditor. Go to modules and click the configure link on your ckeditor. You will need to drag the icon in both the Advanced and Full Profile section. First click edit in the advanced section and click the editor appearance dropdown. Now drag the green film icon from the available buttons section to the current toolbar section. Do the same for the full profile section as well

INSTALL ADOBE FLASH MEDIA ENCODER 3.2

1. Download the Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2 at this link 
   http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html
2. Once Downloaded open the player

YOUTUBE SETTINGS

3. Go to adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html
4. Sign in to your gmail (make sure your gmail is loaded and open)
5. Open a new tab and paste this link
   https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events
6. Click Schedule New Event
7. Enter the event, title, time and description in the appropriate slots. Make sure that “custom” is clicked in the Type Section on the right hand top side of the page and then click Create Event
8. You will then be asked to upload a thumbnail that will be used to advertise the event. Click browse  and locate the file that you wish to use and click open when you select the file.
9. Directly under where you uploaded your picture you will see a dropdown that says Choose maximum sustained bitrate of your encoder. Click “Basic ingestion” and select your video size in the dropdown
10. Next you will see the dropdown that says “Select your encoder” select the Flash Media Live Encoder option in the dropdown menu.
11. In the next dropdown go to number two and click “Download file primary” (do not close your youtube browser window.)
12. Download and save the file and go to your newly installed Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2 that you just installed and hover over the word "File."
13. A dropdown will pop up that says “open profile” and upload the file from step 11 to your media encoder.
14. Make sure your bitrate is 2000kbs and make sure your output and input size is 640x480 and frame rate is 1fps
15. Click the tab that says connect in the right panel or your Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2 and then click the green “Start” button at the bottom of the encoder.
16. Go back to your youtube window and scroll to the top and click the “Live Control Room” link
17. Stream status should be Good if not go to the encoder and click the red stop button at the bottom of the page and then click start again
18. Click the blue “Preview Stream” button
19. Left click the “View on Watch Page Button near the top right corner of the youtube page and open link in new tab
20. Copy the URL at the top of the page in your Navigation Bar
21. Go to embedresponsively.com
22. Paste the Youtube URL that you just copied
23. Copy the embed code from embedresponsively.com
24. Go to the drupal page that you created at the beginning of this tutorial
25. Paste the embed code

YOU ARE NOW LIVE STREAMING USING DRUPAL AND YOUTUBE

Rod J.
BelieveLogix.com